# AngularJS UI Bootstrap Datepicker Date Format in Controller is not correct

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using a datepicker in my html page as follows:

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-controller="StartDateCtrl">
    <label class="control-label" for="startDate">  Date:</label>   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text"  name="startDate" class="form-control" show-button-bar="true" datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="startDate" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'22-06-2015'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**DATE PICKER CONTROLLER**

```
var StartDateCtrl= function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.travelStartDate = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.showWeeks = true;
  $scope.toggleWeeks = function () {
    $scope.showWeeks = ! $scope.showWeeks;
  };

  $scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.travelStartDate = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = ( $scope.minDate ) ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1
  };

  //$scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.formats = ['yyyy-MM-dd'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
};
```

**MAIN CONTROLLER**

```
app.controller('UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl', ['$scope', 'ShoppingBasketFactory', '$location',
                                  function ($scope, ShoppingBasketFactory, $location) {


        alert('START DATE = '+ $scope.startDate );
}]);
```

When the web page is submited, I am retriving the date in the main form controller but the format is different from what is displayed in my date picker popup.
The format shown after selection is for instance '26/03/2014'.
But, in my controller I get :
Thu Mar 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT 0000 (GMT Standard Time)

Please, How do I get the displayed date format in the controller and NOT the "Thu Mar 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT 0000 (GMT Standard Time)"????

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [**date**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) filter for formatting the dates.
Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QvL5A/):

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
   <div>{{date}}</div>
</body>
```

*script*:

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])
       .controller('MyController',function($scope,$filter){
    $scope.date = $filter('date')(Date.now(),'yyyy-MM-dd'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks my fellow Engineer, but the conversion has no effect on the value read. NOTE: The date is formatted correctly on the web page, the issue is with what I am reading in the controller. I tried:  $scope.date = $filter('date')($scope.startDate,'yyyy-MM-dd'); i.e. replacing Date.now() with the scope, but NO joy. Any ideas ..

Comment: Maybe the `startDate` is `String` not `Date` object. So try to convert it to `Date` object. You can do it by `new Date($scope.startDate)`.

Comment: Wow, that worked. I honestly was not thinking along the lines of parsing the date. I thought since the datepicker has a formatting attribute set to 'YYYY-MM-dd', there wont be need to parse it in the controller. But, i still think datepicker should be configurable, so we wont need to do date formatting in AngularJS Controller. What do you think?

Comment: Actually, the datepicker works with `Date` object, not with `String`.It just *decorates* according to specified format and shows in view. For example ,it's like a css. If you have some text in your `div`,  by applying some styles to div , you see the decorated div, not just a black text. So does the datepicker. It 'applies styles' to `Date` object. Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

You need to just simply get the model value in angular filter method and give the date formatting you want. One more thing its need to define `$filter` in your controller as well.

```
var dateValue =$filter('date')($scope.date, 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
```

Answer (score 4):

While this question was answered already, I'll provide an alternative, along with some more detail.

The issue is actually a bug occurring in [Angular 1.3.0 rc0 and onwards](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2659). Another solution, besides using `$filter`, is to define a custom directive as `DaveWM` describes:

```
directive('datepickerPopup', function (){
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
      //remove the default formatter from the input directive to prevent conflict
      controller.$formatters.shift();
    }
  }
})
```

That should have the same effect as using `$filter`.